# Windows DLL global variables

Tags: windows, dll, global-variables

A DLL loaded into a Windows app is composed of an entry point (DLLMain()) and other functions that can be called from there. Now, how do I make a variable global amongst all those functions for every process and thread that attaches to this DLL?

Currently, I need to open/close a file every time one of the functions is called. Since these functions are called very often it is a real performance problem opening/closing the file each time.

```
wofstream wofstr;

int WINAPI func(LPCWSTR lpString) 
{
  ...
  //wofstr.open(...);
  wofstr << lpString << endl; // *** NOT working without opening in this very function
  ...
  //wofstr.close(...);
  ...
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    ...
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        wofstr.open(...); // *** NOT seen in function above
    ...
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    ...
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    ...
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        wofstr.close(...)
    ...
}
```

What am I missing here? What about threads?

Comment: Why don't you open it on demand, i.e. the first time it needs to be used. Then close it when the DLL is unloaded. You may need to periodically flush the output buffer.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I have clarified the example above.

Comment: I mean open the file only once, the first time anyone wants to use it. Use the lazy initialization pattern.

Comment: As I said, if I open/close the file in the wrapper functions it does work. But I don't want to do it that way because it's too much overhead. If I only open it once in DllMain() (so every attaching process/thread should have it) I seem not to be able to use it inside the other functions even though it's a global var for the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Each global variable in a Windows DLL has a single instance for each process that loads the DLL. There is a one-to-one mapping between processes and global variable instances. Processes are completely isolated from each other and one process cannot directly access memory in a different process.

If you want to share a variable between processes then you will need some form of inter-process communication (IPC). For example you could set up a logging app to which your DLL could send messages.

Comment: Alright so why doesn't the file in the example above seem to be open in the func() function above even though it is opened every time DllMain() is called?

Comment: That's a different question whose answer cannot be discerned from the code above. There must be something else going on.

Comment: I've no idea. If you open the file, and later on it is not open, perhaps the open failed or perhaps it was closed. Calling C++ runtime functions from DLLMain is distinctly dubious though. Perhaps that's the problem hard to say.